# Write a text file and go to a new line when there is punctuation

Tags: python-3.x, string, file-io

I have a file, called `input.txt`, structured as follows:

```
Hi Mark, my name is Lucas! I was born in Paris in 1998.
I currently live in Berlin.
```

My goal is to put the text in lowercase, remove numbers and punctuation and replace them with \n (eliminating the excess ones), delete the stopwords and write it all in a new file, called `output.txt`.
So, if

`stopwords = ['my', 'is', 'i', 'was', 'in']`,

`output.txt` should be

```
hi mark
name lucas
born paris
currently live berlin
```

But if I use the following code

```
stopwords = ['my', 'is', 'i', 'was', 'in']
with open('input.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as file:
    new_file = open('output.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8-sig')
    for line in file:
        corpus = line.lower()
        corpus = corpus.strip().replace('’', '\'')
        corpus = re.compile('[0-9{}]'.format(re.escape(string.punctuation))).sub('\n', corpus).replace('\n ', '\n').replace(' \n', '\n')
        corpus = re.sub(r'\n+', '\n', corpus).strip()
        corpus = ' '.join(w for w in corpus.split() if w not in stopwords) # (1)
        new_file.write(corpus)
        new_file.write('\n')
    new_file.close()
```

I get

```
hi mark name lucas born paris
currently live berlin
```

How can I fix it, perhaps by changing only line of code (1)?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should do what you want:

```
import re


# STOPWORDS
stopwords = ["my", "is", "i", "was", "in"]

# The below comprehension will build a regex pattern for each
# word, which will require the word to have a space behind and
# in front for it to be a match. This prevents matching lone
# letters contained within other words.
stopwords = [f"(?<=\s){stopword}(?=\s)" for stopword in stopwords]

# GET INPUT FROM FILE
with open("input.txt", "r") as input_txt:
    text = input_txt.read()

# FORMAT TEXT
text = re.sub("’", "'", text).lower()
text = re.sub(r"[^a-z\u00E0-\u00FF ]", "\n", text)
text = re.sub("|".join(stopwords), "", text)
text = re.sub("[ ]+", " ", text)
text = re.sub("\n[ ]+", "\n", text)
text = re.sub(r"\n+", "\n", text).strip()

# WRITE OUPUT TO FILE
with open("output.txt", "w") as output_txt:
    output_txt.write(text)
```

---

##### Output

```
hi mark
name lucas
born paris 
currently live berlin
```

---

As per your request this now should handle a case where sentences are separated by a line break but no punctuation or number. The issue before was that the `.split()` we were using to separate words would also remove line breaks. To get around this, I had to use quite a bit of regex, so this answer became a whole lot more complicated.

However, I hope it does what you want it to and let me know if it works or you need help understanding any of it.

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks! Just two curiosities:
1) Why did you remove `.replace(' \n', '\n')` at the end of `re.compile(...)`? Was it useless?

2) If I also wanted to stem the words, it would be enough to add `text = " ".join(stemmer.stem(w) for w in text.split())` immediately after the line `text = " ".join(w for w in text.split() if w not in stopwords)`?

Comment: From my testing, yes that line didn't seem to change anything, so I just omitted it. And sorry I'm afraid I'm not familiar with stemming (is it NLTK?) but you could add a `print(text)` and try out whatever you want before writing to the output file.

Comment: Okay, I'll do some tests. However, testing your solution, I found a special case. If a sentence ends with neither a number nor a punctuation character then it does not go to a new line. For example, if my input is
`Hi Mark, my name is Lucas! I was born in Paris\nI currently live in Berlin.`
my output is
`hi mark\nname lucas\nborn paris currently live berlin`
and not
`hi mark\nname lucas\nborn paris\ncurrently live berlin`
Is there a clever way to fix it? Or should I add a period at the end of each sentence?

Comment: Edited the answer, it's a whole lot more complicated now but let me know if it works how you want it to

Comment: I have tested your code and it seems to work, thanks. Another solution would be to move line (1) of my code right after the line where the .lower () is.
However, there would be an extra \n at the end, but it can be solved by iterating to the penultimate line and then processing the last one out of the loop, so as not to print the last \n.

Comment: `Hi Mark, my name is Lucas is! I was born in Paris\nI currently live in Berlin was.` with that solution doesn't get rid of the `was` or `is` because they are right before punctuation. Glad the solution worked out for you though.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I tested your code again and I have two other curiosities (I promise they are the latest haha). 1) Can I remove stopwords after removing punctuation? If so, is it sufficient to move `text = re.sub("|".join(stopwords), " ", text)` right after `text = re.sub(r"[^a-zA-z ]", "\n", text)`? 2) In my native language there are other letters such as à, è, é, ì etc., how can I include them in the selection? Is `regex.sub(r"[^\p{L} ]", "\n", text)` instead of `re.sub(r"[^a-zA-z ]", "\n", text)` exhaustive?

Comment: Edited the answer with some changes, let me know if it works. Removing the punctuation before removing the stopwords seems to work fine, so I put that in the new code. Also, I'm sure `\p{L}` would be exhaustive but I don't think it's available in Python's re module (at least, it gives me an error). So, I replaced with a regex for matching unicode characters, which should work.

Comment: Your solution works. A few clarifications: 1) `\p{L}` works with regex module, not with re module (maybe it is more complete than `re.sub(r"[^a-z\u00E0-\u00FF ]", "\n", text)`?). 2) If I wanted to treat `'` as a blank space and not as a \n, the simplest solution would be `text = re.sub("’", "'", text).sub("'", " ").lower()` in the first line?

Comment: You can try it out, I reckon both work but I suppose `\p{L}` would be more clear (I'm not an expert on regex so not 100% on that).  As for the second question, you can't chain `.sub` onto the end there but a new line with `text = re.sub("'", "  ", text)` should work fine. Replacing it with a space could be weird though, you probably just want to replace it with an empty string. For example with the word `I'm`, you would get a space between the letters, then `i` would get removed so you'd be left with just `m`

Comment: Yes, it would only remain `m` but mine was a general question. You have always used `re.sub()`, can I also use it for general functions (after removing the stopwords)? Something like `regex.sub(r"[^\p{L} ]", function(w), text)`, where `w` is a word identified by the pattern in the first argument of the function `regex.sub()`. At first I used  `' '.join(function(w) for w in text.split())` but obviously it doesn't work anymore. There is no need to change your answer as I consider my initial question resolved. This is just for curiosity in view of future development of my code.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand the question. What function are you calling?

Comment: For example, a function for stemming words.

Comment: If `regex.sub` works the same way as `re.sub` then `regex.sub(r"[^\p{L} ]", function(w), text)` would replace every character that is not a letter or space with the result of `function(w)`, not sure that's what you want

Comment: Yes, I was looking for a way to replace the whole word and not the single character, but I don't know if it's possible using `re.sub()` (I mean, what would be the syntax?). In any case it is not a problem, mine was just a curiosity. Thank you very much for your help in solving this question.

Comment: `re.sub` will use regex to match certain sub-strings, so to match whole words, that's why I have the code which modifies `stopwords` at the top of the script. Then, `text = re.sub("|".join(stopwords), "", text)` takes all the regex patterns from stopwords and joins them using `|` between each word, meaning 'Match this word OR this word OR etc.'. So I'm not sure how you want to use that with a stemming function but of course feel free to ask another question and maybe someone more knowledgeable than me can help out.